# Drag and Drop: by using copyArrayItem() the dragged item should not be removed from start array while drop Angular 8

Tags: angular-material, angular-dragdrop

I have a list of items from where I drag an item and drop it into another list. I'm using ***copyArrayItem()*** method from Angular to not remove the item from the previous array.

I start dragging, the item is within the previous array: the placeholder from that item shows up.

**Start dragging, placeholder shows up**

[image]

I'm leaving the previous array: the placeholder/dragged item disappears (**I want that the placeholder/dragged item stays**) -> the start array has minus 1 items.

**Placeholder disappears, what I don't want**

[image]
I'm on the target array: a placeholder appears in a target array.

I'm dropping the item: item appears now in the start and target array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more research I've found an open issue about that problem:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13906

and there I've found suggestions from participants:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krmecd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This example with workaround helped me to solve this problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o8exzv-jauhhi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html

Maybe this information will be useful for someone.