# CdkDragDrop removing item from source on entering to destination while dragging

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I want to copy item from A to B without hampering A at all. I am using copyArrayItem method for the same. When I am dragging item from a to B, then that item is getting removed from A before it is dropped into B. How can I prevent that behavior before dropping as cdkdragdrop is removing that item.
This is happening after the (cdkDropListExited) event at A and before the (cdkDropListEntered) event at B.

For code I am referring stack blitz link :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css,app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html

Comment: I think you have to use copyArrayItem function for that, instead of transferArrayItem

Comment: I believe this is the exact answer to your problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63844707/3995346

Comment: @MaciejWojcik Thanks but my question is little further. I am currently using copyArrayItem through which I am able to get the functionality of duplicating item. But my question is to prevent removing of item from source while I am entering into destination on drag. Please refer the example to check the behavior.

Comment: well, this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o8exzv-jauhhi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html does that?